# Atomic "insert if not exists" with NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, transactions, rdbms

Consider an application that does something along the lines of:

```
var user = session.QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.Name==name).SingleOrDefault();

if (user == null)
{
    user = new User(name);
    session.Save(user);
}
```

Business rules states that a user's name must be unique, and this is backed by a `UNIQUE INDEX` in the database. The code above works just fine, until two users try to register simultaneously with the same name, both get `user == null` and try to create a new `User`. The first one to commit will suceed, the second one will fail with an exception raised from the database.

One way to avoid such race conditions involves wrapping the critical code in a `lock { }` block, but this will not help when multiple instances of the applications works against the same database. Now, if only I could use the locking mechanisms of the RDBS (MS SQL in this case)…

This is where I got stuck. From what I can read in the NHibernate docs, I might be able to solve it by adding some a hint to my `QueryOver()` chain requesting an explicit lock. This would have to be a table lock, as I have no actual rows yet. Is this possible? How

Alternatively, could I increase the isolation level of the transaction and gain the required locks automatically? Considering that other (non-problematic) queries are made within the same unit-of-work, I suspect this kind of change could introduce a lot of blocking/waiting. Is that so?

Comment: Might be I just found a duplicate for this question: [NHibernate transaction and race condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119762/nhibernate-transaction-and-race-condition)

Answer (score 2):

Increase the isolation level to Serializable. That would acquire both read and write lock across the whole query, including your 'where' clause.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the queries through the same NHibernate session as you save - doing this will ensure that you use the same transaction, leveraging the locking mechanisms of the database automatically.

That said, you *always* need to be prepared for the transaction to fail, and your code needs to handle that case gracefully. Getting fancy with serialised blocks and locks adds complexity to your code but can't eliminate the possibility of failing at the database level, so you're adding that complexity to little gain.

Comment: Both queries are executed in the same transaction already, and I am seeing unique index violations in the exception log. Would I need increase the isolation level on the transaction for the automated locking to work?